# Origin of GUI terminology

Tags: terminology, graphics, history

I'm wondering where the GUI terminology like [modal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window) dialogue comes from.

Who first used these terms? Is there a paper or a book, or was it just sw?

Comment: Please show what you have googled so that others won't do duplicate work.

Comment: "these terms?" If multiple terms are involved, please list at least two of them. Be as specific as possible. Otherwise, people cannot be sure if you are interested, say, "pop-up" dialogue. Are you?

Comment: @JohnL. I just want early GUI terminology, not any specific term. Modal was the only one I could think of that is a good example. "Window" is too general and obvious.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xerox_Star - probably the first computer with GUI software